# SvelteKit UnhandledPromiseRejection with strange TLS Connection error

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, svelte, sveltekit

I have here a strange collection of error, for which i canno't find any solutions on the internet ( maby i'm just bad with google ).

I created a website, with the following files/folder tree:

[image: File tree]

With this setup i first got this error message:

> Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established.

Which I didn't find any solution for other then reload the page.
After deciding handling the error myself i tried this:

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';

const base = process.env['API_ENDPOINT'];
axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 5 });

async function send({ path }) {
    let pages = 0;
    let resp;

    try {
        resp = await axios.get(`${base}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    if ('X-WP-TotalPages' in resp.headers) {
        pages = resp.headers['X-WP-TotalPages'];
    }

    return {
        pages: pages,
        body: resp.data
    };
}

export async function get(path) {
    return send({ method: 'GET', path });
}
```

And i call it in (for example) landing.js:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { browser } from '$app/env';

import * as api from '$lib/api';

let loading = false;
let posts = [];

const list = writable({
    loading,
    posts
});

export default {
    subscribe: list.subscribe,
    async fetchNews() {
        if (loading) return {};
        loading = true;

        list.set({ loading, posts });

        let lang = 'de';

        if (browser) {
            lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'de';
        }

        try {
        const res = await api.get(`posts?filter[lang]=${lang}&per_page=4&_embed`);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        posts = await res.body;

        posts.map((post) => {
            if (post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'])
                post.image = post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url;
            else post.image = '/news/news_placeholder.png';
        });

        loading = false;

        list.set({ loading, posts });
    }
};
```

Now the new error is something like this:

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "Test".] {   code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }

Maybe I'm just an idiot right, but i need really some help here!

Thanks in advance for this.

Comment: `catch (error) { throw error; }` isn't handling the error at all - you may as well remove the `try`  altogether

Comment: I want Sveltekit to show the error screen and thought to hand it upwards!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the whole function body in try {...}, instead of the `const res = await api.get...` line and observe where exactly the error happens.

Comment: I tried this. The Problem here, the TLS error only happens on Vercel and not locally. When i try to simulate it with something liken throw 'Test'; the same UnhandledPromiseRejection error happens